# How do I count and display how many kinds of values I have in a column?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I don’t know how to phrase this in spreadsheet-speak, so here's my example: I have a list of bands (A) with columns for their genre (B), # band members (C), and # instruments (D). I want to know how many genres there are represented in the list, and how many band members and instruments are in each genre programmatically.

In essence, I need a way of turning this:

```
+-----------+--------+--------------+-------------+
| Band Name | Genre  | Band Members | Instruments |
+-----------+--------+--------------+-------------+
| Awesome   | Blue   | 2            | 3           |
+-----------+--------+--------------+-------------+
| Excellent | Blue   | 5            | 4           |
+-----------+--------+--------------+-------------+
| Good      | Red    | 6            | 2           |
+-----------+--------+--------------+-------------+
| Great     | Green  | 3            | 5           |
+-----------+--------+--------------+-------------+
| Fun       | Green  | 7            | 7           |
+-----------+--------+--------------+-------------+
| Witty     | Green  | 2            | 3           |
+-----------+--------+--------------+-------------+
| Charming  | Purple | 4            | 7           |
+-----------+--------+--------------+-------------+
| Tired     | Purple | 8    

    | 8           |
```

+-----------+--------+--------------+-------------+

Into this:

```
+--------+--------------+-------------+
| Genre  | Band Members | Instruments |
+--------+--------------+-------------+
| Blue   | 7            | 7           |
+--------+--------------+-------------+
| Red    | 6            | 2           |
+--------+--------------+-------------+
| Green  | 12           | 15          |
+--------+--------------+-------------+
| Purple | 12           | 15          |
+--------+--------------+-------------+
```

Thanks to any and all who can help.

Comment: There is also the `sumproduct(1/countifrRange,Range & ““))` trick but I would feel uneasy with fractions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of approaches, I am going to pick one.

## Step 1 - Generate a Unique list

Generate a list of unique colours.  There are ways to do this automatically with formulas.  Look up remove duplicates using formulas.  The alternative if your data is short is just type in the duplicates.  Place the list in lets say G2:G5.   Use row 1 for your header row.

## Step 2 - SUMIF

`SUMIF` is a formula that takes the following format:

```
SUMIF(range to check, Check condition, range to sum)
```

In your case, the range to check is the column with all the colours.  Lets assume this is C2:C9.  The first range to sum would D2:D9 and the second range to some is E2:E9.  Based on these assumptions, you would place the following formula in  H2 and copy down and to the right as needed:

```
=SUMIF($C$2:$C$9,$G2,D$2:D$9)
```

## STEP 2 - ALTERNATE COLUMN MATCHING

Alternatively you could sum based on column headers having to match.  You could achieve that with a combination of INDEX and MATCH.  Your formula would look something like:

```
=SUMIF($C$2:$C$9,$G2,INDEX($D$2:$E$9,0,MATCH(H$1,$D$1:$E$1,0)))
```

This will allow for the column to be out of order, or for you to chose only columns you want.

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried both ways and was successful.

Answer (score 0):

Another quick way to do this would be by using [pivot tables](https://www.excel-easy.com/data-analysis/pivot-tables.html). In the pivot table, you can set "rows" to your "Genre" variable and "values" to be sums of those categories you're interested in summing.

Comment: Consider expanding your answer with some instruction and a worked example.  The readers who will benefit from this aren't yet familiar with pivot tables.  For them, this is really just a comment about an approach to investigate.